# Images aren't changing on call

Tags: android, xml, image, kotlin

So this my pictures are supposed to change each time the value of limonadeState is being changed. But...they don't.

Can the reason for that be that the images are XML?

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post your code as text. Refer this for the reason to do so, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not listening for changes of limonadeState.
assuming you put when statement inside the Activity's onCreate method, and onCreate runs only once in a lifecycle @see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

to achieve your expected behaviour, extract when statement and wrap inside a function and call manually on `limonadeState` state changes.